# drupal rules i have to create a history table when users does some action

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

can any tell me how to perform this task

i need to create history table when ever user performs certain task like

when he creates a content, browse a specific page, perform search...

i have started with created a content type history and i have written a rule
to insert one row in the table..

it works fine 
but when i create a view to display the results it doesn.t show up.
only the rows which i have created manually(create content-> history),the view display only this results..

any other way to see the database query when the node is created.

i have tried with the firebug module but don know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devel module gives a lot of debugging functions. It'll let you either print stuff to the page or to a log file. You can also use the Drupal extension for firefox and print it to the console instead.

I don't use the firebug addon/module combo myself, so wont comment on that. I would recommend using it over devel though. I've just gotten used to devel and how it works that I haven't bothered / needed to switch yet.
To use devel, you need to call either `dpm()` to get your debugging printed to the screen or `dd()` to get it printed to a log file. The log file is created in the tmp file dir, that is selected in the file settings.

Comment: can u tell me how to use firebug

Comment: can u tell me how to do it with an example